# How to lock zoom in Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook, zoom

In the Macbook Pro you can zoom anywhere on the screen by holding down control and moving the mouse up. The problem is that if the mouse goes to the edge of the screen, then the area that is showing moves to follow the mouse. I don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 2):

In System Preferences, Universal Access, Zoom Options, the 3rd section of the pane has some other choices of how the screen should move to keep the pointer in view.

Comment: I didn't see any options that would fix the problem.